# Translate HQL subqueries to Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like to translate this structure of HQL:

```
FROM Entity_1 obj
WHERE obj IN (FROM Entity2) OR 
      obj IN (FROM Entity3)
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in Hibernate criteria documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries

A DetachedCriteria can also be used to express a subquery. Criterion instances involving subqueries can be obtained via Subqueries or Property.

```
DetachedCriteria avgWeight = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Cat.class)
    .setProjection( Property.forName("weight").avg() );
session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Property.forName("weight").gt(avgWeight) )
    .list();

DetachedCriteria weights = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Cat.class)
    .setProjection( Property.forName("weight") );
session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Subqueries.geAll("weight", weights) )
    .list();
```

Correlated subqueries are also possible:

```
DetachedCriteria avgWeightForSex = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Cat.class, "cat2")
    .setProjection( Property.forName("weight").avg() )
    .add( Property.forName("cat2.sex").eqProperty("cat.sex") );
session.createCriteria(Cat.class, "cat")
    .add( Property.forName("weight").gt(avgWeightForSex) )
    .list();
```

Comment: Thank you! but it is still not clear to me how to apply this to my exposed problem? could you edit your question to put some pseudocode with the solution? thanks!

Comment: Your subqueries should be implemented by DetachedCriteria instances, then used in your main Criteria.

Comment: Yes, I Know that, but i don't know how tho apply the "IN" clause.

Comment: You have a method Subqueries.in(...) in Hibernate.

Comment: I know, and it expects 2 parameters, the first of them is "Object value", and I don't know how to apply it to my case (since i don't have any value at all). I have studied the API deeply, and **i am starting to think that Criteria isn't expressive enought to make this query in a single invocation**. I would invite you to edit your answer, erase the copy&paste from the documentation, and put the solution to my question, or erase the answer otherwise. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to HQL but I would suggest something like the following:

```
 DetachedCriteria sub1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Entitiy2);
 DetachedCriteria sub2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Entity3);

 Criteria criteria = getYourSession().createCriteria(Entity_1.class, "obj");
 criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Subqueries.propertyIn("obj", sub1), Subqueries.propertyIn("obj", sub2));
```

Please, correct me if I am wrong.